# MVC Date Picker Not working in firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Im using this date picker for MVC, its working for **google chrome** but not working **fire fox** , how can i fix it? please give em a solution
**view**

```
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

**script**

```
<script >
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); 
});
</script>
```

this is [example this](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-datepicker/)

Comment: try add  name="datepicker" and clear browser then try again. you can also use browser console to js references working correctly.

Comment: What is not working? What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: no any error , date picker drop down menu not working in fire fox, really work in google chrome

Comment: @Cola did you try this inside the document.ready function? Did chrome shows any console messages regardless of working

Comment: its here  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Normal datepicker doesn't work properly on IE or firefox, as it works on chrome. The best choice is using some third party datepicker. My suggestion is using bootstrap datepicker([here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). Or you could use some popular datepicker like telerik datepicker([here](http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/datepicker/index)).